# Document did not loop to find all document for "Active" status

Tags: lotus-notes, lotusscript

I have a process called PC Inspection. When copy inspection, batch no will be change every time inspection is done. And there is pc inspection form called EmpPCSpec. It will copy data from computer document.

I can create batch but it only created for one document selected only.

Below are the lotusscript code to set new batch and create pc inspection form.

```
Sub Click(Source As Button)
  Dim session As New NotesSession
  Dim workspace As New NotesUIWorkspace
  Dim db As NotesDatabase
  Dim collection As NotesDocumentCollection

  Set db = session.CurrentDatabase
  Set collection = db.UnprocessedDocuments

  Dim ws As New NotesUIWorkspace
  Dim uiview As NotesUIView
  Set uiview = ws.CurrentView

  answer% = Messagebox("Do you want to set batch number?", 4,"Batch Number")
  If answer% = 6 Then

    InputBatchNo = Inputbox("Please insert the Batch Number.  eg : 2014A")

    If Not InputBatchNo="" Then

      For ii = 1 To collection.count
        Set doc = collection.GetNthDocument(ii)

        currbatchno = doc.PBatchNo(0)
    '--------------------------------------
    Gosub SetNewBatchNo
    '---------------------------------------
    doc.PBatchNo =newbatchno

    '------------ set new acceptance form ---------------------------
    If doc.PStatus(0) = "Active" Then
    Set comdoc = New NotesDocument (db)
    comdoc.Form = "EmpPCSpec"

    comdoc.ATagNo = doc.PTagNo(0)
    comdoc.AYear= Left(InputBatchNo,4)
    comdoc.ADept= doc.PDept(0)
    comdoc.AUserName= doc.PUserName(0)
    comdoc.AUserID= doc.PUserID(0)
    comdoc.AUserGroup= doc.PUserGroup(0)
    comdoc.ALocation= doc.PLocation(0)
    comdoc.AStatus= doc.PStatus(0)
    comdoc.ABatchNo=doc.PBatchNo(0)

    comdoc.AProcessor= doc.PProcessor(0)
    comdoc.ASerialNo= doc.PSerialNo(0)
    comdoc.ABrand= doc.PBrand(0)
    comdoc.AModel= doc.PModel(0)
    comdoc.AType= doc.PType(0)
    comdoc.ADisplayUnit= doc.PDisplayUnit(0)
    comdoc.ADisplaySize= doc.PDisplaySize(0)
    comdoc.ADisplayBrand= doc.PDisplayBrand(0)
    comdoc.ARam= doc.PRam(0)
    comdoc.AHDD= doc.PHDD(0)
    comdoc.AIPAddress= doc.PIPAddress(0)
    comdoc.AOperatingSys= doc.POperatingSys(0)
    comdoc.ACalLicense= doc.PCalLicense(0)

    Call comdoc.ComputeWithForm(False,False)
    Call comdoc.save(True,True)

    '----------------------------------------------------------------

    Call doc.ComputeWithForm(False,False)
    Call doc.save(True,True)
      End If
    Next

    Messagebox("Process completed." & Chr(13) & "Press 'F9' to refresh the view.")

  Else
    Messagebox("Please insert Batch Number.")
  End If

End If

Exit Sub

SetNewBatchNo:

    currbatchno1 = Strtoken(currbatchno, "-", 1)

    If InputBatchNo = currbatchno1 Then
        seqno = Strtoken(currbatchno, "-", 2)
        newseqno = Val(seqno) +1
        newseqno1 = Format(newseqno, "0000")

        newbatchno = InputBatchNo + "-" + newseqno1
    Else
        newbatchno = InputBatchNo + "-" + "0001"
    End If

    Return

End Sub
```

How can I get all document where if status is "Active" by looping it? Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a number of issues with this code: using getNthDocument should be avoided as it is a performance killer and bad practice - at least for larger collections as the code will recalculate the position of the document on every use of getNthDocument. Use getFirstDocument and getNextDocument instead. The same is true for the logic with goto. This is difficult to read, understand and especially to maintain. I suggest you create a logic like this:

```
Set collection = db.UnprocessedDocuments
set doc = collection.getFirstDocument()
while not doc is nothing
    if doc.status(0) = "Active" then

        <your logic goes here>

    end if

//next doc for processing
set doc=collection.getnextdocument(doc)
wend
```

Besides the above mentioned issues I think the issue with your code is that you did not establish any sort of looping through all selected documents -  getNthDocument() is executed only once, therefore only one document is being touched. But as I already said it is dificult to read and understand when and where the code jumps to during runtime due to the use of goto.

Comment: Hey, thank you for your solution. I manage to get all Active document. May I know, what is the problem logic with goto?

Comment: In my opinion it is preferrable to use control elements like if, select case (switch), local subs and functions - the code is easier to read and understand (especially for other developers and colleagues) and increases maintainability. Using elements like goto or gosub can result in confusing code executions as the code is not necessarily executed in the top-down-order, code can jump outside of loops and ifs etc. There are exceptions (e.g. on error goto ...) where it is abolutely fine and necessary though :)

Comment: Oh, alright noted. I will change it. Thanks for your opinion.